# SFML c++ проблемы с установкой

Tags: c++, sfml

Скачал sfml для c++ по официальной инструкции https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/start-cb.php. Использую Code::Blocks. При запуске программы из урока вылезают ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то изображения великоваты... при определенных усилиях кое-что даже можно прочесть... :(

Comment: система не обнаружила libstdc++-6.dll; система не обнаружила libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

Comment: Скопировать эти dll-ки из папки с компилятором в папку со своим exe-шником. Второй вариант - добавить папку с компилятором в начало PATH - но копировать их к себе все равно придется, чтобы распространять программу другим людям, лучше привыкать.

Answer (score -1):

Значит нужно установить библиотеки libstdc++-6.dll и libgcc_s_seh-1.dll

Comment: Это dll файлы из папки CodeBlocks. Они там с установщика.

Comment: Да, проверь просто, может быть у тебя их нет